# prove $((A \times A) \cup (B \times B) = C \times C) \to ((A\subseteq B \lor B\subseteq A) \land (A \cup B \subseteq C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

First of all, I prefered to find a way proving the above-mentioned statement directly (not by the contradiction way).

however, I couldn't realize how to handle a proof of the kind "if A then B and C" (how do you prove such statments?), so I tried the contradiction way but also without too much success. would appreciate your help.

this is what I've got: (as I understand, continued to the contradiction proof, I had to show that if $A \cup B \subseteq C$ then somehow $A\not=B$ but it's also contradicting the assumption as needed)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\left(A\times A\right)\cup\left(B\times B\right)=\left(C\times C\right)$
it can easily be deduced that $A,B$ are subsets of $C$ or equivalently
that $A\cup B\subseteq C$.

Also from $\left(A\times A\right)\cup\left(B\times B\right)=\left(C\times C\right)$
it can easily be deduced that $C\subseteq A\cup B$, so actually we have
$C=A\cup B$.

If $b\in B\setminus A\wedge a\in A\setminus B$ then $\langle a,b\rangle\in C\times C=\left(A\times A\right)\cup\left(B\times B\right)$
leading to $b\in A\vee a\in B$.

So a contradiction is found and
we conclude that $B\setminus A=\varnothing\vee A\setminus B=\varnothing$
or equivalently $B\subseteq A\vee A\subseteq B$.